# How to autowire service in another module?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am working on application which contains few sub modules. On one of these modules I have service with header like this:

```
@Transactional
@Service("mySimpleService")
public class MySimpleServiceImpl implements MySimpleService {}
```

On the another module I have a controller in which I would like to use one of the MySimpleService method. So I have something similar to this:

```
@Controller
public class EasyController {    

    @Autowired
    private MySimpleService mySimpleService;

    @RequestMapping("/webpage.htm")
    public ModelAndView webpage(@RequestParam,
                                @RequestParam,
                                HttpServletRequest request,
                                HttpServletResponse response) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(”webpage”);
        mav.addObject(”name”, mySimpleService.getObject());
        return mav;
    }
}
```

On the line `mav.addObject(”name”, mySimpleService.getObject());` I am getting `NullPointerException`. I don't know why. I am not getting error similar to `Could not autowire field` but only `NullPointerException`.

I have also created my own interceptor in this way to check some another ideas in my task:

```
public class CustomInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MySimpleService mySimpleService;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, 
                             HttpServletResponse response,
                             Object handler)
                             throws Exception {         
        request.setAttribute("attr", mySimpleService.getAttribute());
        return true;
    }    
}
```

This interceptor is of course declared in dispatcher servlet. In my logs I can see `NullPointerException` at line: `request.setAttribute("attr", mySimpleService.getAttribute());`. So this is exactly problem with getting access to service from another application module.

How can I achieve this?

I have heard about ideas like building EJB with my service and share it using `JNDI` or using Maven - copy folder with my service to target module during building application. I have tried to do the second option but it isn't working and I can't check if the coping was successful. Is possible to check Maven based solution? Do you have another suggestions?

**EDIT**

This is component scaning from target module dispatcher servlet:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="my.package.target.module.controller" annotation-config="false"/>
```

Comment: How are you loading your beans? Using `context:package-scan` or are they all defined in an xml file loaded by some `*ApplicationContext` ?

Comment: @Alex : I have edited my question and I have added line from target module dispatcher servlet. I am using as you can see `context:component-scan`.

Comment: try adding the `@Qualifier("mySimpleService")` annotation and check what happens. Also, set @Autowired(required=true)`. That'll give you better debugging

Comment: Sorry. Forgot `required=true` is set by default

Comment: @VarunAchar : I will check this out and I will write the result here tommorrow.

Comment: @VarunAchar : adding `@Qualifier("mySimpleService")` doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is the annotation-config="false". The annotation-config feature is what turns on the @Autowired annotation.  Without auto-wiring, your mySimpleService properties do not get injected and remain null.  Then you get the NullPointerException.

Try

```
<context:component-scan base-package="my.package.target.module.controller" annotation-config="true"/>
```

BTW - I have never used this exact configuration, since I don't do scanning. I always use the separate element:

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

Comment: I have to check this out. Setting `annotation-config` to true will cause including `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` and `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`. I don't know at this moment is this good for my application. I will check that.

Comment: Great! It's working. I have to check out issue with these `PostProcesssors` now. I will inform here about it.